# Spring-Boot Login without Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

I currently have an application that has a working login and registration page. Everything was going smoothly and all test cases were working until I got to a scenario where the password required a unique one. It would throw an error if a user logged in with a password that was the same as an existing one. Could someone lead me in the right direction to figure this bug out? I would assume it would be something in the controller but I am not 100% sure. I am also using the built in h2 memory database.

EDIT: I also just tested another use case, I am not checking if the associated email put in has the correct password, I am only checking if the data put in are in the database.

**This is the Main Controller**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepo;

    public MainController(AccountRepository accountRepo) {
        this.accountRepo = accountRepo;
    }





        @RequestMapping(value="/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String registerAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountForm") AccountEntity accountForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return "error";
            }

            //Grabs information from view and saves them to attribute to save to database
            model.addAttribute("userName", accountForm.getUserName());
            model.addAttribute("email", accountForm.getEmail());
            model.addAttribute("firstName", accountForm.getFirstName());
            model.addAttribute("lastName", accountForm.getLastName());
            model.addAttribute("password", accountForm.getPassword());
            model.addAttribute("age", accountForm.getAge());
            //model.addAttribute("gender", accountForm.getGender());

            //Email Verification
            String randomVerificationCode = RandomString.make(64);
            accountForm.setVerificationCode(randomVerificationCode);


            AccountEntity emailChecker = accountRepo.findByEmail(accountForm.getEmail());
            AccountEntity usernameChecker = accountRepo.findByUserName(accountForm.getUserName());


            //checks if an email and username are unique;
            //if email or username already exists in database, throws error
            if(emailChecker != null || usernameChecker != null){
                System.out.println("the email or username already exists");
                return "redirect:registration";
            }
            else{
                accountRepo.save(accountForm);
                return "redirect:login";
            }

    }

        @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("login", new AccountEntity());
            return "login";
        }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitLoginIn(@ModelAttribute("login") AccountEntity account){

        AccountEntity accountFormEmail = accountRepo.findByEmail(account.getEmail());
        AccountEntity accountFormPassword = accountRepo.findByPassword(account.getPassword());

        // Can't login if passwords are the same as an existing account --> need to fix
            if(accountFormEmail == null || accountFormPassword == null)
            {
                System.out.print("Account does not exist");
                return "redirect:login";
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("account exist");
                return "redirect:welcome"; //Change later
            }

        }

}
```

**This is the AccountEntity**

```
package com.CSCI4050.TermProject.CovidWebsite.entities;

import javax.management.relation.Role;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity (name = "user")
public class AccountEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    //private String gender;
    private Integer age;
    private String verificationCode;

    //Getters and Setters
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /*
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
   */

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getVerificationCode() {
        return verificationCode;
    }

    public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    }

}
```

**This is the login.jsp**

````
<%@ page import="java.net.URLDecoder" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required MetaFiles -->
    <meta name="content-type" content="text-html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
    <meta name="description" content="this is my page">
    <!-- Webjars for Bootstrap and Jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/login.css"%></style>
    <title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
<%--@elvariable id="login" type=""--%>
<form:form modelAttribute="login" >
    <div class="form-group container" id="positionOfLogin" style="text-align: center">
        <div>
            <form:input type="email"
                   class="form-control MyInput"
                   id="email"
                   style="display: inline; width: 300px;"
                   placeholder="email@example.com"
            path="email"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:input type="password"
                        name="password"
                   class="form-control MyInput"
                   id="password"
                   placeholder="password"
            path="password"/>
        </div>


        <div>
            <form:button type="submit" style="text-align: center" class="form-control MyButton">Login</form:button>
        </div>

        <div>

            <a href="/registration"
               type="submit" class="form-control MyButton" >Sign Up</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</form:form>

</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Not really following the question and what is the meaning of this sentence; "got to a scenario where the password required a unique one. It would throw an error if a user logged in with a password that was the same as an existing one". Also unable to follow the logic in the login method of the controller. Can you clarify what is the expected vs actual behaviour?

Comment: @Setu sorry if the question didn't make sense! My problem was that for the login process, it was searching the whole database and not correlating the password with the username; for example... email is abc@gmail.com and password was 123; we have another account def@gmail.com and password was 1234; when trying to login, it would allow you to login with abc@gmail.com and password 1234. I wasnt checking if the password and email correlated with each other. I fixed it though! I had to grab the instance of the email in the database; instance.getEmail and get the email inputted into the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your password is saved with plain, current logic is ok. But security level is too low. I suggest you encode password with MD5 then save to DB. The same string encoded with MD5 has same result. So you can avoid save plain password in DB.

The MD5 encoder is not safety currently because there are more decoder way online. You should protect DB well. It is a good way to suggest user change password in period.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on that! I knew the project was not secured. I ended up using Argon2 as my password encoder.